# Will Postgres Deadlock on Single Update

Tags: postgresql, transaction, deadlock

If the two updates given in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS happen in one `UPDATE` query will it still result in deadlock?

Transaction 1 executes the following statement:

```
-- transaction 1
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100.00 WHERE acctnum IN (11111, 22222);
```

Transaction 2 executes the following statement:

```
-- transaction 2; note the acctnum order is different
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 100.00 WHERE acctnum IN (22222, 11111);
```

Please note that `acctnum` order provided in queries is different. Please ignore the fact that account balance will be incorrect. I am interested in the behavior as I have a similar situation.

Comment: The order of the values in the `in` clause is not significant, rows may be visited in a non-deterministic order.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the values in the `in` clause is not significant.

the rows may be visited in any order, this order can change at any time.

however with such a small set of targets and in the presence of an ordered index (not a hash index) the records will probably be visited in index order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these statements can deadlock each other.

The fact that the transaction they're part of has only this single instruction does not suppress the possibility of a deadlock.

The false hope that it would might come from an optimist interpretation of what **[atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))** provides at the instruction level. An UPDATE does not acquire several row locks in a single atomic grab: it has to grab them one by one, and any of them has a separate chance to be impossible to acquire.

The question's query comes from the documention at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html, except there it's shown as two independent queries processing a single `acctnum`. Surely, if updating two rows in the same query solved the deadlock problem, the doc would mention it at this point. It does not mention it because it's not true.

Comment: This would mean the deadlock can occur depending on the order in which the rows are visited. If they are not based on order provided in the query (based on what @jasen mentioned above) then it is not safe to use one query and the only way to avoid deadlock is use individual updates in deterministic order. Am I correct?

Comment: an alternative approach would be to look for deadlocks and retry them,.